# Preg Match for strings inside square brackets and @strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to get strings inside `[square] [brackets]` and also those `@like @this`. The following works for the `[tags]` but not the `@users`.

```
$query = "[tag1] [tag2] @user1 @user2 ignoreme";

// check for tags e.g. [tag1] [tag2]
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]+)\]/", $query, $tags);

// check for users e.g. @username
preg_match_all("/\B@[^\B]+/", $query, $users);

print_r($tags);
print_r($users);
```

Output:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [tag1]
            [1] => [tag2]
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => tag1
            [1] => tag2
        )
    )
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @user1 @user2 ignoreme
        )
    )
```

The tag `preg_match` is working but the @user one just grabs everything after it (even ignoring the second @user2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at this explanation: http://regex101.com/r/fH4lG4 you'll find out why your regex is broken.

You're matching everything BUT the literal `B`.

What you should be doing is either `[^@]+`, `[^@ ]+` or `\S+`

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! `[^@ ]+` was what I was looking for :) BTW, in the output why does the tag preg_match remove the `[]` whereas the `@` pregmatch leaves it?

Comment: No problems! That is because you have encapsulated the data in the first expression with () = capturing parentheses. Have a look over here: http://regex101.com/r/fN4zO6

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in one simple Regex

```
/((?<=\[)\w*(?=\])|(?<=@)\w*)/
```

Try it yourself here: http://www.regex101.com/r/iH8iJ5